# Removing part of a filename with mv

Tags: bash, mv

How would I rename all -m.css files to .css with the shell utility mv?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a for loop:

```
for file in *-m.css ; do mv "$file" "${file%-m.css}.css" ; done
```

Using `rename` might be less verbose.